# Why does flex give hr element width of 0?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I try putting an `hr` element inside a container with `display: flex`, it disappears. (If I remove `display: flex`, it reappears, so I'm confident that is the cause.)

I read on a [blog post](https://www.bersling.com/2017/01/17/i-cant-see-my-tag-horizontal-line-where-did-it-go/) that flex causes the `hr` to have a width of zero, which I confirmed by giving it a width of 100% (making it reappear), but no explanation was given.

Out of curiosity (I simply put the `hr` outside the flex container to solve the problem), why does this occur? Will using flexbox cause other random elements to disappear as well?

I don't think something else in my code is causing this, but in here's my full code just in case:

```css
* {
  /* Makes width and height include padding, border */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #2d3c49;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  /* Browsers typically display h1 as 2em */
  font-size: 2.6em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* Adds a bit of space above subtitle (set h1 bottom margin to 0) */

header h4 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}


/* Top content */

header {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
  /* Vertically centers logo  */
  align-items: center;
}


/* logo img */

.logo {
  height: 90px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* Only subtitle isn't aligned all the way to the right; this fixes it. TODO: figure out why doesn't apply to h1 text */

.header-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

hr {
  background-color: #7d97ad;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: none;
  height: 3px;
}

.main-image {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Applies to content within <main> element (excludes header, footer) */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Applies to project section (including header text) */

.container-projects {
  display: flex;
  /* Parent container needs this for flex-item to take full width in row */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.portfolio-header {
  /* Puts header in its own row without removing from container with row flex direction (setting parent container to wrap also required) */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  color: #7d97ad;
}


/* Div containing single project's title, image, text */


/* TODO: add declarations */

.project {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.project p,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Images cropped with 3:2 ratio, scaled resolution down to 600 x 400 */

.project-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}


/* Remove default 1em margin-top */

footer p {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/* Applies to Font Awesome social icons */

.fab {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  color: white;
}


/* Changes social icon color to dark grey on hover */

.fab:hover {
  color: #2d3c49;
}


/* Media queries (breakpoints correspond to Bootstrap breakpoints). 1rem = 16px */


/* Small devices (landscape phones) */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  /* Doesn't seem to be doing anything TODO: find out why   */
  .portfolio-header {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  /* TODO: make slightly wider  */
  .container-projects {
    margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
  }
  header {
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  }
  header,
  .container,
  footer {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  /* Must specify max-width for img even though parent .container has the same declaration because max-width isn't inherited */
  .container img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .project {
    /* Centers projects (aligned left otherwise) */
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  /* Aligns portfolio header text flush left of portfolio rows */
  .portfolio-header {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  .logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
  }
}


/* Tablets */

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
  }
}


/* Small laptops */

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jVeP4S/udacity_logo.png" alt="Udacity logo" class="logo">
  <!-- Header is set to display: flex, and it only works on direct children. Without the div, its default row alignment puts header text side by side, but inside a div, it works on the div as a block and since header text items are no longer direct children, it has no effect on them -->
  <div>
    <h1>Natalie Cardot</h1>
    <h4 class="header-text">Front-End Web Developer</h4>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- TODO: put inside main? But makes it disappear -->

<main class="container">
  <hr>
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cTcuM7/using_laptop_large.jpg" alt="Woman using laptop at home during the day" class="main-image">
  <section class="container-projects">
    <h2 class="portfolio-header">Featured Work</h2>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/hv4c8n/santorini_small.jpg" alt="View from island of Santorini on a sunny day">
      <h3>Project No. 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/c9sKM7/coast_small.jpg" alt="Distant view of a rugged island with a sailboat nearby">
      <h3>Project No. 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/eO9oES/mediterranean_small.jpg" alt="Bird's eye view of a rocky beach with clear turquoise waters">
      <h3>Project No. 3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End of container-project -->
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Created by me</p>
  <!-- "fab" prefix new in Font Awesome version 5 (released 3/18) -->
  <a href="https://github.com/nataliecardot" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a href="https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/"><i class="fab fa-codepen fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/nataliecardot/"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/natalie-cardot/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-lg"></i></a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `hr` element has default styles set by the browser. For example, here is what Chrome does:

[image]

In a flex container, `auto` margins consume all free space in the direction of the margin.

So `-webkit-margin-start: auto` (in LTR, the equivalent of `margin-left: auto`) and `-webkit-margin-end: auto` (in LTR, the equivalent of `margin-right: auto`), consume all free space to the left and right of the `hr` element, compressing it to `width: 0` (since there is no content inside).

You could override these `auto` margins with `width: 100%`. But it's probably more efficient to simply override `margin: auto` with `margin: 0`.

But even then, in this case, once you remove the `auto` margins, `align-items: center` kicks in from the parent.

[image]

This overrides the default `align-items: stretch` and does the same thing the left/right `auto` margins were doing. Again, the `hr` is compressed to `width: 0`.

So make these two adjustments to your `hr` rule:

```
hr {
  margin: 0;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```css
* {
  /* Makes width and height include padding, border */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #2d3c49;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 200;
  /* Browsers typically display h1 as 2em */
  font-size: 2.6em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* Adds a bit of space above subtitle (set h1 bottom margin to 0) */

header h4 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}


/* Top content */

header {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
  /* Vertically centers logo  */
  align-items: center;
}


/* logo img */

.logo {
  height: 90px;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* Only subtitle isn't aligned all the way to the right; this fixes it. TODO: figure out why doesn't apply to h1 text */

.header-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

hr {
  background-color: #7d97ad;
  max-width: 1000px;
  /* margin-bottom: 1em; */
  border: none;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;    /* NEW */
  align-self: stretch;  /* NEW */
}

.main-image {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
}


/* Applies to content within <main> element (excludes header, footer) */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Applies to project section (including header text) */

.container-projects {
  display: flex;
  /* Parent container needs this for flex-item to take full width in row */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.portfolio-header {
  /* Puts header in its own row without removing from container with row flex direction (setting parent container to wrap also required) */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  color: #7d97ad;
}


/* Div containing single project's title, image, text */


/* TODO: add declarations */

.project {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.project p,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Images cropped with 3:2 ratio, scaled resolution down to 600 x 400 */

.project-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}


/* Remove default 1em margin-top */

footer p {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/* Applies to Font Awesome social icons */

.fab {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  color: white;
}


/* Changes social icon color to dark grey on hover */

.fab:hover {
  color: #2d3c49;
}


/* Media queries (breakpoints correspond to Bootstrap breakpoints). 1rem = 16px */


/* Small devices (landscape phones) */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  /* Doesn't seem to be doing anything TODO: find out why   */
  .portfolio-header {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
  /* TODO: make slightly wider  */
  .container-projects {
    margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
  }
  header {
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  }
  header,
  .container,
  footer {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  /* Must specify max-width for img even though parent .container has the same declaration because max-width isn't inherited */
  .container img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .project {
    /* Centers projects (aligned left otherwise) */
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  /* Aligns portfolio header text flush left of portfolio rows */
  .portfolio-header {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  .logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
  }
}


/* Tablets */

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
  }
}


/* Small laptops */

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jVeP4S/udacity_logo.png" alt="Udacity logo" class="logo">
  <!-- Header is set to display: flex, and it only works on direct children. Without the div, its default row alignment puts header text side by side, but inside a div, it works on the div as a block and since header text items are no longer direct children, it has no effect on them -->
  <div>
    <h1>Natalie Cardot</h1>
    <h4 class="header-text">Front-End Web Developer</h4>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- TODO: put inside main? But makes it disappear -->

<main class="container">
  <hr>
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cTcuM7/using_laptop_large.jpg" alt="Woman using laptop at home during the day" class="main-image">
  <section class="container-projects">
    <h2 class="portfolio-header">Featured Work</h2>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/hv4c8n/santorini_small.jpg" alt="View from island of Santorini on a sunny day">
      <h3>Project No. 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/c9sKM7/coast_small.jpg" alt="Distant view of a rugged island with a sailboat nearby">
      <h3>Project No. 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/eO9oES/mediterranean_small.jpg" alt="Bird's eye view of a rocky beach with clear turquoise waters">
      <h3>Project No. 3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End of container-project -->
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Created by me</p>
  <!-- "fab" prefix new in Font Awesome version 5 (released 3/18) -->
  <a href="https://github.com/nataliecardot" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a href="https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/"><i class="fab fa-codepen fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/nataliecardot/"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/natalie-cardot/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in fa-lg"></i></a>
</footer>
```

---

Note that  flex `auto` margins take precedence over keyword alignment properties (such as `justify-content` and `align-items`). If an `auto` margin is set, that applies first, consuming all free space on the line. `align-items` goes second, but there is no free space left, so it can't do anything.

That's why, in the code above, `align-items` does nothing until the `auto` margins are removed.

> [**8.1. Aligning with `auto`
>   margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any
>   positive free space is distributed to `auto` margins in that
>   dimension.
>
> If free space is distributed to `auto` margins, the alignment
>   properties will have no effect in that dimension because the margins
>   will have stolen all free space left over after flexing.

More details about flex `auto` margins:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: I had a similar problem. When putting an `hr` in a flex container with column direction set, the height will be 0 even when applying `margin: 0`. The solution I found is instead of setting the `height`, one must set the `min-height` for the `hr`. Also I should mention that the `hr` has a background color set (gradient) and that it's border is none.

Answer (score 6):

Flex breaks the margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto of the HR tag. Try adding this to your CSS.

```
hr {margin-left:0;margin-right:0}
```